# Is there a better way of writing variableName[0]?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a better of writing `const data = variableName[0]`? I mean for `variableName[0]`. I do understand data is placed in index 0, but writing a number does not look professional ( to me atleast), So if there is some professional way someone knows, please share

To be more accurate, this is the case when the array has ONLY 1 element

Comment: *"but writing a number does not look professional "* Why?

Comment: To be more accurate, if array has ONLY 1 index, I mean, in that case

Comment: `variableName[0]` makes the intention very clear, it's easily readable and better than all the answers posted here. Again, this is primarily opinion-based.

Comment: You want to have a more "professional" alternative than using `array[0]` (of which is the fastest approach...) because you have troubles with numbers? Granted, there are different ways to access an element from a given array but there's something that people needs to keep in mind when writing solutions; *keep it simple*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to use the [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) syntax:

```js
const variableName = [1];
const data = variableName[0];
console.log(data);

const [data2] = variableName;
console.log(data2);
```

In above example it takes first array element and ignores the other ones. You can also destructure more than one element into named variables:

```
const [variable1, variable2] = yourArray;
```

Comment: I would suggest to expend the example for an array of multiple indices and exporting the 2nd entry with the destructuring assignment, to just clarify the usage even more.

Answer (score 2):

or a modern approach

```js
    const arrayData = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    const variable = arrayData.at(0)
    console.log(variable)
```

Comment: What are the advantages of this?

Comment: @AnnanYearian array[array.length-1] === array.at(-1)

Comment: Ah, so the advantage is consistency. If you want to use `.at(-1)` then should use `.at(0)` elsewhere.

Comment: @AnnanYearian it's up to you. just did a test  - .at is slower than indexed access. I thought differently

Answer (score 1):

The following is the shortest syntax in the modern JavaScript:

```js
const [data] = variableName;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say that what looks potentially unprofessional is not so much writing a number, but rather storing data in an array like this. If your variable was an object `{data: "someData"}` instead of an array `["someData"]` , then you could write

```
const {data} = variableName;
```

If you can't change the format, then there is nothing really wrong with `variableName[0]`, but if you really want to avoid writing a number you could write

```
const [data] = variableName;
```

This may look a bit more cryptic to people not used to this syntax, though.

Answer (score -2):

You can use spread operator.
I'm really sorry for the first answer, try with this

```
const [first,...data] = arr
console.log(first);
```